# How to fix git committed unidentified user after I push all my files to my github

Tags: git

I have problem regarding pushing my files to github, after i push my project folder to the github. it shows other committed user, which that is not me, I think that user is the old programmer who use the laptop that I use today. I currently new in github, How to change the committed user that connected. I wan't to him logout then I want to use my own user

This is the command that I use to push my folder files.

Reference: https://help.github.com/en/github/importing-your-projects-to-github/adding-an-existing-project-to-github-using-the-command-line

```
git push origin master
```

[image: Problem]

Comment: You should probably _not_ try to alter the commit which you already pushed, assuming the branch might have been pulled by someone else.  Instead, `git revert` the bad commit with the wrong other, then `git config user.name` to fix the username problem and push again.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen i will try first and i will give you feedback thanks

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen after i config new it shows this On branch master Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'. when i command the git commit -m "updating"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to change the email and username in your local configurations and add the correct ones of your GitHub account:

```
git config --global user.email "your mail"
git config --global user.name "your user"
```

You can omit the `--global` flag if you wish to set changes for a single repository instead of the global configurations.

Now you can revert the commit and push again in order for the changes to take effect.

Comment: i will try first then i will give you feedback

Comment: after i config new it shows this On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'. when i command the git commit -m "updating"